# How to get a Web app to run on a given LocalHost Port (Apache)?

Tags: java, apache, http, get

I am new to developing client/server interfaces.

I have a client facing app which sends a GET request to server based on an action. I currently have this running on the localhost setup by apache. I created my own directory in /var/www and made changes to the config files.

I have a server running that I have written in Java. It is listening on port 8888. Now when I type http://localhost:8888 - my server crashes with a NumberFormatException For input string: "Host: localhost:8888"

What is it I need to do in order to run my client on the specific port? Why am I receiving a get request when I haven't sent anything?

I've tried searching for similar questions and made edits to the config files by changing the default port 80 to 8888 both in ports.conf and 000-default.conf followed by a restart. This however causes both localhost and localhost:8888 result in nothing.

Comment: It depends on server which you are using.

Comment: I'm using apache2

Comment: Hi, apache2 is not written in Java

Comment: it is not possible to use Apache for java.
It can be Tome Cat, Glass Fish, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is treating the HTTP headers wrong: when you enter http://localhost:8888 in your browser, you will receive (among other things) a header like this:

Host: localhost:8888

Apparently, you server is trying to convert this line into a number.